How to simplify an expression involving `Sin[k Arg[z]]` with an integer k
Consider the following:
$Assumuptions = k \[Element] Integers;
Sin[k Arg[-Conjugate[z]]] - Sin[k Arg[z]] 

According to my calculations, if $z = |z| e^{i \phi}$, then:
$-z^* = -|z| e^{-i \phi} = |z|e^{i(\pi-\phi)}$
Meaning that the original expression can be simplified to:
Sin[k (Pi - Arg[z])]] - Sin[k Arg[z]]

Which can be further simplified to:
- Sin[k Arg[z]]*(1 + (-1)^k)

Is it possible to ask Wolfram to perform such simplifications when the above pattern appears multiple times in a certain expression?

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.
